# loop function to clear field

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

trying to create a high-low game with loop function to count the amount of tries and allow the user to keep re-entering until the random number generated matches the entered value by the user, get the output messages for if it's too low or too high but doesn't loop the function or clear the field to allow another guess

here's what i have so far;

```
/**
* A very simple guessing game program.
* 
* The program thinks of a random number between 1 and 100
* and then asks the user to guess the number.  An 
* appropriate message is displayed depending upon a right
* or wrong answer.
* 
*/

import javax.swing.*;       // JPanel, JLabel, etc
import java.awt.event.*;    // ActionListener, ActionEvent
import java.awt.*;          // Color
import java.util.*;         // Random Class


class HiLo8 implements ActionListener
 {
// Define object references
JFrame myFrame;
JPanel myPanel;
JButton startButton, makeGuessButton, submitButton,
        playAgainButton, exitButton;
JLabel message1Label, message2Label, message3Label; 
JTextField inputNumberTxtField;
Random randomGenerator;
int    randomNumber;

// Constructor method
HiLo8()
{
    // Set up frame
    myFrame = new JFrame("Guess a number game");

    // Set up panel object.  Use absolute positioning.
    myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setLayout (null);


    // Create a random generator object
    randomGenerator = new Random();

    // This push button is used to start the game off.
    startButton = new JButton ("Press to start game...");
    startButton.setBounds (10, 30, 400, 30);

    myPanel.add (startButton);

    // This label object (initially with no string)
    // will be used to let the user know that the
    // program is thinking of a number
    message1Label = new JLabel ();
    message1Label.setBounds (10,80,500,20);
    myPanel.add (message1Label);

    makeGuessButton = new JButton ("Click to make your guess.. ");
    makeGuessButton.setBounds (10, 140, 400, 30);
    myPanel.add (makeGuessButton);

    // This label object will be used to prompt the 
    // user to enter a number
    message2Label = new JLabel ("What is the number? ");
    message2Label.setBounds (10, 200, 500, 20);
    myPanel.add (message2Label);

    // The textfield object where the user types in 
    // a number.  A default value of 1 is provided
    inputNumberTxtField = new JTextField ("1");
    inputNumberTxtField.setBounds (220, 200, 30, 20);
    myPanel.add (inputNumberTxtField);

    // After the user types in a number (guess), 
    // he/she must then press this button to continue
    submitButton = new JButton ("Submit your guess");
    submitButton.setBounds (300, 200, 150, 30);
    myPanel.add (submitButton);

    // This object (initially empty) will let
    // the user know whether the guess or right
    // or wrong
    message3Label = new JLabel();
    message3Label.setBounds (10, 250, 500, 20);
    myPanel.add (message3Label);



    // This push button allows the user to
    // exit the application.
    exitButton = new JButton ("Exit Game");
    exitButton.setBounds (250, 300, 100, 30);
    myPanel.add ( exitButton );

    // The following components are initially made
    // invisible
    message2Label.setVisible ( false );      
    makeGuessButton.setVisible (false);
    inputNumberTxtField.setVisible (false);
    submitButton.setVisible (false);        
    exitButton.setVisible ( false );


    // Register all push button objects
    // for an ActionEvent
    startButton.addActionListener (this);
    makeGuessButton.addActionListener (this);
    submitButton.addActionListener (this);
    exitButton.addActionListener (this);

    // Add panel to frame
    myFrame.add (myPanel);

    // Size frame and make it visible
    myFrame.setBounds(50,100,500,450);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);

   }

  // Implement the actionPerformed method
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  event)
    {
      // Local variables
      String str;
      int number;
      int numberOfTries = 0;

      // Did the user press the Start button
      if ( event.getSource() == startButton)
        {
            // Disable the startButton for now
            startButton.setEnabled ( false );

            // Tell user the program is thinking of a 
            // number
            message1Label.setText ("Thinking of a number between 1 - 100");

            // Generate a random number between 1 to 100
            //   nextInt (100) generates a random no.
            //   between 0 to 9, so add 1 on to scale up
            randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;
            numberOfTries++;

            // Make the makeGuess button visible
            makeGuessButton.setVisible ( true );

        }
       else // Check to see if it's the makeGuessButton 
       if ( event.getSource() == makeGuessButton )
          {
              // Disable makeGuessButton for now
              makeGuessButton.setEnabled ( false );

              // All the elements asking the user to
              // make a guess and submit answer are now 
              // made visible
              message2Label.setVisible ( true );
              inputNumberTxtField.setVisible ( true );
              submitButton.setVisible ( true );
              // Make sure the cursor is in the textfield
              inputNumberTxtField.requestFocus();
          }
       else // Check to see if it's the submit button 
       if ( event.getSource() == submitButton )
          {
              // Read the contents off the textfield
              str = inputNumberTxtField.getText();
              // Convert to an integer number
              number = Integer.valueOf ( str );

              // Disable textfield and submitbutton
              inputNumberTxtField.setEnabled ( false );
              submitButton.setEnabled ( false );

              // Check to see if user guessed correctly
              if ( number == randomNumber )
                {   // Guessed correctly
                    message3Label.setText ("Well done.  You've guessed correctly" + " it's taken " +       numberOfTries + " tries");
                }
              else if ( number < randomNumber )  // Otherwise, got it wrong!
                {
                    message3Label.setText ("Your guess is too low" + " it's taken " + numberOfTries + " tries");
                }
              else if ( number > randomNumber )  // Otherwise, got it wrong!
                {
                    message3Label.setText ("Your guess is too high" + " it's taken " + numberOfTries + " tries");
                }

              // Make the exitButton 
              // visible
              exitButton.setVisible ( true );
          }
        else // exitButton pressed
        if ( event.getSource() == exitButton )
           {
               System.exit (0);   // Exit the application
           }

  }

 // main() method - this is where program class execution
 // starts
 public static void main()
   {
       HiLo8 start = new HiLo8();
   }

   }
```

Comment: Can you clarify, what's wrong with your code, what are you trying to do. Also, you might want to use `equals()` to compare objects.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code a bit but left comments in /* */ so you can differentiate them from your own. Check it if this is how you wanted your code to work for you. Friendly advice though when you're making an application that uses JFrame setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) is your friend.

```
/**
* A very simple guessing game program.
* 
* The program thinks of a random number between 1 and 100
* and then asks the user to guess the number.  An 
* appropriate message is displayed depending upon a right
* or wrong answer.
* 
*/

import javax.swing.*;       // JPanel, JLabel, etc
import java.awt.event.*;    // ActionListener, ActionEvent
import java.awt.*;          // Color
import java.util.*;         // Random Class


class HiLo8
 {
// Define object references
JFrame myFrame;
JPanel myPanel;
JButton startButton, makeGuessButton, submitButton,
        playAgainButton, exitButton;
JLabel message1Label, message2Label, message3Label; 
JTextField inputNumberTxtField;
Random randomGenerator;
int    randomNumber;

/*
 * variables moved from local to global
 */
String str;
int number;
int numberOfTries = 0;

// Constructor method
HiLo8()
{
    // Set up frame
    myFrame = new JFrame("Guess a number game");

    // Set up panel object.  Use absolute positioning.
    myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setLayout (null);


    // Create a random generator object
    randomGenerator = new Random();

    // This push button is used to start the game off.
    startButton = new JButton ("Press to start game...");
    startButton.setBounds (10, 30, 400, 30);

    myPanel.add (startButton);

    // This label object (initially with no string)
    // will be used to let the user know that the
    // program is thinking of a number
    message1Label = new JLabel ();
    message1Label.setBounds (10,80,500,20);
    myPanel.add (message1Label);

    makeGuessButton = new JButton ("Click to make your guess.. ");
    makeGuessButton.setBounds (10, 140, 400, 30);
    myPanel.add (makeGuessButton);

    // This label object will be used to prompt the 
    // user to enter a number
    message2Label = new JLabel ("What is the number? ");
    message2Label.setBounds (10, 200, 500, 20);
    myPanel.add (message2Label);

    // The textfield object where the user types in 
    // a number.  A default value of 1 is provided
    inputNumberTxtField = new JTextField ("1");
    inputNumberTxtField.setBounds (220, 200, 30, 20);
    myPanel.add (inputNumberTxtField);

    // After the user types in a number (guess), 
    // he/she must then press this button to continue
    submitButton = new JButton ("Submit your guess");
    submitButton.setBounds (300, 200, 150, 30);
    myPanel.add (submitButton);

    // This object (initially empty) will let
    // the user know whether the guess or right
    // or wrong
    message3Label = new JLabel();
    message3Label.setBounds (10, 250, 500, 20);
    myPanel.add (message3Label);



    // This push button allows the user to
    // exit the application.
    exitButton = new JButton ("Exit Game");
    exitButton.setBounds (250, 300, 100, 30);
    myPanel.add ( exitButton );

    // The following components are initially made
    // invisible
    message2Label.setVisible ( false );      
    makeGuessButton.setVisible (false);
    inputNumberTxtField.setVisible (false);
    submitButton.setVisible (false);        
    exitButton.setVisible ( false );


    // Register all push button objects
    // for an ActionEvent
    /*
     * actionListener for startButton
     */
    startButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Disable the startButton for now
            startButton.setEnabled ( false );

            // Tell user the program is thinking of a 
            // number
            message1Label.setText ("Thinking of a number between 1 - 100");

            // Generate a random number between 1 to 100
            //   nextInt (100) generates a random no.
            //   between 0 to 9, so add 1 on to scale up
            randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;
            /*
             * i removed this since logically you should only be increasing 'tries' when the submitButton is pushed
             */
            //numberOfTries++;

            // Make the makeGuess button visible
            makeGuessButton.setVisible ( true );

        }
    });

    /*
     * actionListerner for makeGuessButton 
     */
    makeGuessButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Disable makeGuessButton for now
              makeGuessButton.setEnabled ( false );

              // All the elements asking the user to
              // make a guess and submit answer are now 
              // made visible
              message2Label.setVisible ( true );
              inputNumberTxtField.setVisible ( true );
              submitButton.setVisible ( true );
              // Make sure the cursor is in the textfield
              inputNumberTxtField.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    /*
     * action listener for submitButton
     */
    submitButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Read the contents off the textfield
              str = inputNumberTxtField.getText();
              // Convert to an integer number
              number = Integer.valueOf ( str );

              /*
               * increase number of 'tries'
               */
              numberOfTries++;

              // Disable textfield and submitbutton
              /* inputNumberTxtField.setEnabled ( false );
               * submitButton.setEnabled ( false );
               * keep the textField and button enabled until the user guesses properly
               * otherwise the user wont be able to make another guess
               */
              // Check to see if user guessed correctly
              if ( number == randomNumber )
                {   // Guessed correctly
                    message3Label.setText ("Well done.  You've guessed correctly" + " it's taken " +       numberOfTries + " tries");
                    /*
                     * disable the textField and button
                     */
                    inputNumberTxtField.setEnabled(false);
                    submitButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
              else if ( number < randomNumber )  // Otherwise, got it wrong!
                {
                    message3Label.setText ("Your guess is too low" + " it's taken " + numberOfTries + " tries");
                }
              else if ( number > randomNumber )  // Otherwise, got it wrong!
                {
                    message3Label.setText ("Your guess is too high" + " it's taken " + numberOfTries + " tries");
                }

              // Make the exitButton 
              // visible
              exitButton.setVisible ( true );
        }
    });
    /*
     * actionListener for exitButton
     */
    exitButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    // Add panel to frame
    myFrame.add (myPanel);

    // Size frame and make it visible
    myFrame.setBounds(50,100,500,450);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }

 // main() method - this is where program class execution
 // starts
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       HiLo8 start = new HiLo8();
   }

   }
```